# A difficulty in the proof of partial converse I.(p. 24 in Guillemin & Pollack)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, proof-explanation, differential-topology, geometric-topology

The statement and its proof is given below:

[image]

But I am wondering: How can I check that 0 is a regular value for $g$?

Comment: "Just do this and check that" usually indicates that the proof is straightforward if you know the definitions. What makes you think it is not? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Use the chain rule perhaps? You'll also need to know some other things as well which should come from the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using G&P's hint, take a chart $(\psi, W)$ in $Y$ centered at $y$, which means $\psi(y)=0_{\mathbb{R}^l}$. Then the map $g=\psi \circ f$ takes any point $x\in f^{-1}(y)$ to $0_{\mathbb{R}^l}$. It's just left to prove that the coordinates of this new map $g=(y^1, \dots, y^l)$ are independent functions. Just observe that at any $x\in S=f^{-1}(y)$ we have ker $df_x=T_xS$, so $df_x$ sends any subspace complementary to $T_xS$ in $T_xX$ isomorphically onto $T_yY$. This means that the map $g:f^{-1}(W)\supset S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^l$ has rank $l$ at every $x\in S$ (because $\psi$ is a diffeomorphism, so its derivative is an isomorphism), which is another way to say that  $y^1, \dots, y^l$ are independent in $S$.

Comment: why $ker df_{x} = T_{x} S$?

Comment: Because $f$ will take any curve in $S$ through $x$ to the constant point $y\in Y$, so its tangent vector goes to zero through $df_x$. That proves that $T_xS\subset$ ker$df_x$. To prove that it is exactly ker$df_x$, observe that by this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) well-known theorem of Linear Algebra, $dim ker (df_x)= dim X - dim Im (df_x)= dim X- dim Y= dim S= dim T_xS$. So these subspaces coincide.